# Connection attempt rejected by fms server

Tags: flash, flash-media-server

I'm trying to access harvard cs 109 videos but I'm getting the following error-
'Connection attempt rejected by FMS server. Connection failed'

Answer (score 3):

I contacted havard and got the following reply :-

Dear Sharma,

Thank you for contacting Harvard Online Support. The FMS error you received is because those particular videos are from several semesters ago and are no longer hosted.

Go to the CS109 Data Science website (linked below) and click the Slides/Videos link at the top of the page.  You will be able to watch any video Listed as HD.   Any video listed as SD Recording / SD Mobile is actually from the Legacy system and will no longer work.

http://cs109.github.io/2015/

Please be aware that any availability of these lecture videos or the Web page itself are subject to change by the instructor without notice.

Because this is an old course we will be resolving this incident, but if you have any issues streaming these lectures or require clarification, feel free to reply to this email with as much information as possible.

Also, I noticed that you are attempting to view these lectures on a Linux machine.  Please be aware that Linux is not supported for these lecture videos and we cannot vouch for your experience with this operating system.

Check out the Video Guidelines Page below for system requirements.  Note that recent testing indicates that the minimum Internet speed is 2 - 3 Mbps.

https://www.extension.harvard.edu/academics/courses/types-courses/video-course-guidelines

We apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused!

Best,

--
Evan Maze
Harvard University
Division of Continuing Education
Academic Technology Support
Support Hotline: (617) 998-8571
Support Email: AcademicTechnology@dce.harvard.edu

Answer (score 1):

The videos are removed, confirmed by Distance Education Support, Harvard. 'The FMS error you received is because those particular videos are from several semesters ago and are no longer hosted on our retired lecture system, SD Legacy.' I wrote a complaint to DCE support and they told me that the videos are no longer hosted. They told me to access cs109 fall 2015. Link for the same- cs109.github.io/2015 –